# Cherrypick single revision from remote repository?

Tags: git, github, git-cherry-pick

Let's say there is the project repository (on GitHub) and my fork (also on GitHub). My fork is identical except contains one revision to a single file (a bug fix) which hasn't (yet) been accepted by the project repository. I'm trying to provide installation instructions to a third party about how to download the latest version of the software, including my bug fix.

As far as I know, they'll have to do this:

```
git clone http://projectrepo
git remote add myrepo http://myrepo
git fetch myrepo
git cherry-pick a12345
git remote rm myrepo
```

(Assume I do not intend to maintain myrepo up to date - I would like my instructions to outlive my involvement with the project, which could end soon. Also assume that other changes could take place to this file, so simply downloading a copy of the whole file is not safe.)

A few suboptimalities with this:

1. They need to transfer two whole Git repos
2. It's three extra commands just to get one file.

Are there better solutions? Can you obtain a single revision a simpler way?

Comment: Use the git protocol, git://somerepo, it's much faster. git rarely if ever pulls objects you already have, it doesn't care where the objects came from.

Comment: Why do they need to apply the patches themselves? can't you point them to your repo, which already includes your bug fix?

Comment: @CharlesB: see the statement about not maintaining myrepo.

Comment: @SteveBennett: OK, didn't understand at first read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip the `remote add`/`remote rm`:

```
git clone http://projectrepo
git fetch http://myrepo remote-branch-name
git cherry-pick a12345
```

If you know the commit is the HEAD of `remote-branch-name`, then you can do `git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Anything wrong with just creating a patch file and telling them to apply it?  You could even save it as a gist to avoid having to email it.

Create the patch:

```
git format-patch -1 a12345
```

Apply it:

```
git clone http://projectrepo
cd projectrepo
wget https://raw.github.com/gist/<patch-file>
git am -3 <patch-file>
```

Comment: Err, that's a perfectly cromulent solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT there is no need to manually tell git to fetch both repos.  You can just go

```
git clone http://myrepo
cd myrepo; git co <rev/branch> # maybe
```

And git/github takes care of all the details.

Comment: Yeah, but then they wouldn't get the benefit of future improvements to the main project repo.